# Haskell String Rotation Function

Tags: string, haskell

I need to write a Haskell function that that takes a `String`, `s`, and an `Integer`, `i`, then performs `i` rotations right on `s`.

`rotate :: String -> Integer -> String`

I have been successful in getting it to work with `String -> Int -> String` but I am being asked to do it with `Integer`

This is what I have implemented with `Int`:

`` rotate str n = take (length str) $ drop (negate n `mod` length str) $ cycle str ``

Comment: 1. Show the `Int` version you got working. The `Integer` version should be very similar.

Comment: 2. The "parentheses piece" just means that the first argument to `func1` is itself a function.

Comment: 3. Please post separate questions when you have two unrelated issues you are asking about.

Comment: You can make use of functions like `genericTake` to use any `Integral` type: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:genericTake

Comment: I have separated the questions, and will make a new post for the other one, the function genericTake did not work for me. I already attempted using that and was unsuccessful, however i am very new to haskell

Comment: just stick a `fromInteger` onto the problematic argument ,like e.g. `let { i::Integer ; i=1 } in drop (fromInteger i) [1,2]` works. also, avoid `length` as much as possible. you don't need it here at all.

Comment: Why are you using `mod` on the `drop` but not the `take`? That looks wrong,

Comment: I am using take its at the beginning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that [**`drop :: Int -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:drop) takes an `Int` as type parameter. Furthermore [**`length :: Foldable f => f a -> Int`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:length) for example produces an `Int`. So that will not work.

There are however generic variants that work with `Integral` types or `Num` types, for example [**`genericDrop :: Integral i => i -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:genericDrop) and [**`genericLength :: Num i => [a] -> i`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:genericLength):

```
import Data.List(genericDrop, genericLength, genericTake)

rotate :: Integral i => [a] -> i -> [a]
rotate str n = genericTake l (genericDrop ((-n) `mod` l) (cycle str))
    where l = genericLength str
```

Comment: I implemented this method without changing my function too much and it worked beautifully, For some reason, VSCode was throwing wonky errors on genericTake earlier but it seems to have resolved itself,